# Creating MSI in VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis, wix, windows-installer, installshield

I have a website developed using VS 2012 and created an MSI (Deployment Package) using the "Install Shield Limited Edition Project" available in VS 2012. While i am trying to install this application in a Win 7 system, it is creating a new AppPool as "ASP.NET v4.0 DefaultAppPool" and installing the application with this AppPool.

But if there are any previous application installed in the same system with the application pool as "DefaultAppPool", then my application's AppPool ("ASP.NET v4.0 DefaultAppPool") is getting applied for those previously installed applications (which has "DefaultAppPool" as its application pool) too.

Is there any settings that i am missing while creating the MSI using the Install Shield? Please advise on this

Answer (score 1):

If you need flexibility in IIS installation the only serious alternative in my opinion is the open source [**WIX toolset**](http://wixtoolset.org/).

I don't have time to write a proper answer right now, but please try these two earlier posts:

1. [Wix generate single component id for entire tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548374/wix-generate-single-component-id-for-entire-tree)
2. [Warning in Wix Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958181/warning-in-wix-setup)

Also [**check this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546941/129130) out to get an explanation of why WiX is best for this purpose. And definitely read the section on using **dark.exe** to decompile an existing MSI to get a WiX source file to start with.