# installshield 2011 install IIS error

Tags: installshield, installshield-2011

I'm using InstallShield 2011 to create a install package.
When I install package in windows server 2012, DefaultAppPool is not overwrite and name of website display incorrect.

Example:
- In IntsallShield: I config name Website is "Shopping" but when I install complete IIS is display name "Website2"

Comment: It may be worth evaluating a more recent version; InstallShield 2011 does not officially support Windows 8 or Windows Server 2012. (But that's assuming your case works on a earlier OS; if it does not you should fix that first.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using **[Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/)** (free and open source) if you need detailed control of the installation of IIS applications.

It has a learning curve. [**Please see this answer for some quick start tips**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130).

Some further links:

- [Good resources for learning how to create MSI installers from WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310418/good-resources-for-learning-how-to-create-msi-installers-from-wix)
- http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/main/wix_learning.html
- [Wix generate single component id for entire tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548374/wix-generate-single-component-id-for-entire-tree)
- [Warning in Wix Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958181/warning-in-wix-setup/22960351#22960351)
- [Creating MSI in VS 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205099/creating-msi-in-vs-2012/24208266#24208266)
- [MSI vs nuget packages: which are is better for continuous delivery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-package-what-is-better-for-continues-delivery/25005864#25005864)